# Need details on the Ubuntu version 18 and 20 recent security patches released

Tags: lubuntu

Can someone help with the details on the recent security patches that has been released of Ubuntu 18 and 20. Mostly i am seeing application related rpm but not the complete package information

Any inputs would be of great help.

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/security/cve has all you need

Comment: We can offer more specific advice and assistance if you ask a more specific question.

Comment: Ubuntu releases using the *year* for are different products to the far more widely used *year.month* format.  Ubuntu products using the *year* format (eg. Ubuntu Core 18) are *snap* only and intended for server/appliance/cloud use - and applications are identical for all releases (ie. upgrading from Ubuntu Core 18 to 20 changes no applications as *snap* packages run on any release).  That does **not** apply to the more common *year.month* products which are *deb* package based thus changes apply. Lubuntu is a desktop system and is thus *deb* based, with no 18 or 20 *snap* only release.

Answer (score 3):

https://ubuntu.com/security/cve contains all the information about CVEs.  You can look these up by each CVE or each package to get the list of certain CVEs that are marked as still affecting a release and are unpatched.

Also watch https://ubuntu.com/security/notices for notices of security updates being released.

Wherever you're getting your 'rpm' information is not including the Ubuntu security patching processes.

However, without more information from you about *which* CVEs you're looking at specifically, it's impossible to give you a better answer than this.